# Kleisli exponentiation in Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin

I tried to write the Kleisli exponentiation in Kotlin:

```
fun <A,B> kleisli(n: Int, f: (A) -> B): (A) -> B = if (n == 1) f else { it -> f(kleisli(n-1, ::f)(it)) }
```

that just composes `f`, `n` times (please do not put `n = 0` in my code).

Kotlin (1.0.6) complains `error: unsupported [References to variables aren't supported yet]` pointing at the `::f`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use just `f` instead of `::f`, it is already a functional value (i.e. a **parameter**, a variable or a property of a functional type), so you don't need to make a callable reference of it.

```
 ... else { it -> f(kleisli(n - 1, f)(it)) }
```

Also, your example seems to have a type mismatch: `kleisli(n - 1, f)` returns a function of type `(A) -> B`, which is called on `it` of type `A`, returning a result of type `B`. Then the result is passed to `f`, but `f` can only receive `A`. To fix that, you can remove type parameter `B` and leave only `A`:

```
fun <A> kleisli(n: Int, f: (A) -> A) : (A) -> A = 
    if (n == 1) 
        f else 
        { it -> f(kleisli(n - 1, f)(it)) }
```

<sup>[(runnable demo of this code)](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/v5bmdlkaua21kke0ckml0shsc9/cdalk9l0etud7ohnud8g8ish4a)</sup>

---

Also, this code demonstrates the intention perfectly well in functional style, but it might result into redundant objects allocation and undesired call stack growth. It can, however, be rewritten into imperative style, which will work more efficiently:

```
fun <T> iterativeKleisli(n: Int, f: (T) -> T) : (T) -> T = { x -> 
    var result = x
    for (i in 1..n)
        result = f(result)
    result
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. Seems like I need to know much more about Kotlin. And also sorry for missing that to compose f, f needs to be a->a.

Comment: Just for curiosity, what does that error mean (references to variables aren't supported yet)?

Comment: @Koyomi-chan, if it was supported, `::f` would mean a callable reference to the parameter `f` of the function -- an object containing some information about that parameter and providing a way to get its value. There are already [function references](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#function-references) and [bound callable references](https://gist.github.com/udalov/f86fbea722a53730f3f5777d871ab8ba) in Kotlin, both using `::`. But local variable and parameter references are not supported for now.